# Problem with Picasso while binding image to recyclerview

Tags: android-recyclerview, adapter, picasso

I am not able to bind my image from firebase to recyclerview using Picasso.
Is it incorrect to bind this way?

```
Picasso.get().load(img).fit().centerCrop()
                        .into(imgViewUser)
```

Hope someone with experience with Picasso can give me some guidance. Thank you so much in advance.

```
@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
            override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserViewHolder, position: Int, model: Game) {
                val tvGameName: TextView = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeading)
                val imgViewUser: View? = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleImage)

                tvGameName.text = model.documentId
                val img: URI = model.images?.get(0)
                Picasso.get().load(img).fit().centerCrop()
                    .into(imgViewUser)


                //val tvCounter: TextView = holder.itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)
                //val tvLang: TextView = holder.itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)
                //tvCounter.text = model.counter.toString()
                //tvLang.text = model.documentId

                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "image is $img", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
        rvUsers.adapter = adapter
        rvUsers.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    }
```

Comment: did you try glide? Click [here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for a reference!

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is the wrongly assigned imgViewUser as View, which should have been ImageView. Now it is all good. Tks!

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.